# В чем разница в mysql в кластерном индексе и не кластерном?

Tags: mysql

Подскажите какая разница между индексами кластерный и не кластерным и что можно почитать об этом?

Comment: оба типа - Б-деревья, кластерный ссылается на записи самой таблицы, некластерный на их копию. почитать например https://habr.com/post/141767/

Comment: @Lexx918 честно говоря, то я все равно не особо понял в чем именно разница. Можно как то подробнее о том как хранятся данные при том и втором индексе?